Where can I call to get copy of HUD Settlement statement from 2005 when the Lender and Title both are Closed and no longer in Business?
I was trying to get an approval of a HELOC on my home and an old Lien from 10/2004 still appears on my Title. It states, New Century Title closed my loan back in August of 2005.  I looked up New Century Title and says “Disillusioned in 2008” no longer in business.  I never received the old Reconveyance/or Release of Lien from the previous loan for $225,000 recorded on 2004 from Novastar Mortgage, I do have the Deed of Trust.
I called Novastar Mortgage, they filed Bankruptcy no longer in business and all their documents were destroyed and they have nothing to provide me.  I really need your advice,  I need the copy of the original HUD Settlement statement showing Novastar Mortgage was PAID OFF by First Allied Funding on 8/2005. With that document is the only evidence I have, so I can remove this Old Lien from my Title. Can you provide information what other steps to take?  I tried calling New Century Title all their phone numbers are disconnected and the Records show no longer in business and all show "Permanently Closed".  Where do I go from here, this needs to resolved and removed from Title of my home.  I really appreciate your help.

Who currently has the lien on your property?

Do you still have a contact with "First Allied Funding"? Presumably if they were the lender, they'd also have a copy.
